# Changing the settings value of dll without recompiling

Tags: wpf, plugins, dll, app-config, application-settings

I have created a plugin dll, which is being referred by third party application. My plugin refers to a webservice endpoint. When i deploy the plugin, i should be able to point to manually edit the end point address without rebuilding the dll. Just like how the exe will pick up change when its config file is edited.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Service endpoints and other configuration-related things should be stored in [application configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229689%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

These files are deployed together with the application binaries and might be changed at any time, without requiring recompliation.

Typical app.config file containing some service references:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://MyServer/MyApplication/MyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap1"
                contract="IMyService" name="MyServiceSoap" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <!-- service bindings configuration -->
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

For further instructions, refer to the linked MSDN article.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your reply, but in my scenario, i want to edit any custom value specified in Settings file of my Plugin dll after it is deployed. The webservice proxy is consumed in another dll to which i need to pass the endpoint address from my plugin.

Comment: @prashant You can perfectly do that. Please read the documentation.